# Create editable html/css website

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a website with some content in it:

```
<p> Here is my content </p>
```

When administrator logs in, he wishes to edit this content. Which programming/designing tools should I use to add this feature?

Comment: Heard of [**Wordpress**](http://wordpress.org/), [**Joomla**](http://joomla.org/), [**Drupal**](http://drupal.org/)?

Comment: search "CMS" in google.com

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I **wouldn't** suggest **Drupal** for the user who is taking first look into CMS. It might turn him not to use any CMS at all in the future as far as this is one of the most complicated CMS which needs deep understanding on it's entities to be able to work with it.

Comment: @WhiteAngel I agree with you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need some kind of dynamic language. Something like PHP, Python or similar. This would give you the tools to build a secure area for an administrator to log in and make edits.  You'd then need to use this language to write some function to display the pages, create the URLs, update menus etc etc.

You would also need some kind of database like MySQL or PostgreSQL for instance to store the content of the pages.

All in all it doesn't seem like a worthwhile idea to roll your own script for this. We have a saying in web development - "don't reinvent the wheel". Wordpress would be my recommendation for you. It's not my favourite CMS but it is incredibly well documented - for beginners in particular - and it'll give you everything you need to get going. It also has an option were an administrator could log in and then use the front end of the site and just click edit when they want to make a change to the page they're on.

Comment: I am using java spring framework for backend, but thank you for your tips :)

Answer (score 1):

For editing content and enabling user login you can use PHP. You can code your own site/blog or you can use scripts that already exists. You should read more about PHP / MySQL on w3schools or some similar site.

Things you should learn that I recommend you :

1. **PHP**
2. **mySql**
3. **Wordpress**

Visit **[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/)** for more details about PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Storage.** Normally, you will need to have DB where you will store all the date, user access details, e.t.c. Sure, this can be done via text files (html, xml, txt e.t.c.) but this doesn't make much sense.
2. **Editing** You need some kind of editor if you don't want your administrator to edit plain HTML. You can try any of WYSIWYG editors.
3. **All other things** You might need in the future other things connected to editing (save labels, use keywords, insert images e.t.c) - all of this is already done in any CMS.

According to all of this info I would suggest you to take on of ready-to-use CMS which can hold all of these features from scratch (e.g. WordPress, Joomla or any other).